# Counting the frequency of values in a list Using Control.Foldl

Tags: haskell

I am using the `Control.Foldl` library to traverse an arbitrarily long list and counting all occurrences of arbitrarily many unique entities. Ie, the list may be of form

```
[Just "a", Just "b", Just "aab", Nothing, Just "aab"]
```

and I my result should something like:

`[(Just "a",1),(Just "b",1) (Just "aab", 2), (Nothing, 1)]`

Now the issue is I do not have the name of these entities a priori, and I would like to dynamically update the results as I fold.

My problem is that I do not know how to describe this computation in terms of the `Fold` data type from `Control.foldl`. Specifically, at each step of the fold I need to traverse the result list and ask if I have seen the current item, but I see no way of describing this using `foldl`.

Please note for future use purposes it's **really** important that I use the Control.Foldl library here, not fold over some other foldable data type like a map. In some sense my question is more along the lines of how to use the Foldl library, since the documentation is not too clear to me.

Edit: The example I showed is just a toy example, in reality I need to traverse a arb large list many times computing statistics, hence I'm using the foldl library, which allow me to combine the computations using applicatives ie `toResults <$> stat1 <*> stat2 <*> ... <*> statm $ largeList` and foldl allow me to traverse the list just once, computing all m statistics. Please find a solution using the foldl library.

Comment: The example I showed is just a toy example, in reality I need to traverse a arb large list many times computing statistics, hence I'm using the foldl library, which allow me to combine the computations using applicatives ie `toResults <$> stat1 <*> stat2 <*> ... <*> statm $ largeList` and foldl allow me to traverse the list just once, computing all m statistics.

Comment: One thing doesn't exclude the other. You can make your "histogram" a `Map (Maybe String) Int` (or whatever is appropriate) and still use a `Fold` to build it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can encode a normal `foldl'` pretty straightforwardly as a `Fold`:

```
foldlToFold :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> Fold a b
foldlToFold f z = Fold f z id
```

I'm actually a bit puzzled that this combinator isn't in the library...

Anyways, if you have

```
foldl' f z
```

you can replace it with

```
fold (Fold f z id)
```

so here, you would normally be using

```
foldl' (\mp x -> M.insertWith (+) x 1 mp) M.empty
```

with `Fold`,  you'd be making

```
countingFold :: Ord a => Fold a (Map a Int)
countingFold = Fold (\mp x -> M.insertWith (+) 1 mp) M.empty id
```

and you can use it as

```
countUp :: Ord a => [a] -> Map a Int
countUp = fold countingFold

-- or
countUp = fold (Fold (\mp x -> M.insertWith (+) 1 mp) M.empty id)
```

If you want to go back to a list at the end, you can do

```
M.toList . countUp
```

In general, if you can formulate your fold as a `foldl'`, you can do the transformation above to be able to encode it as a `Fold`.  `Fold` is a bit more expressive because for `foldl'`, the `b` type is both the accumulator and the result type; for a `Fold`, you can have a separate accumulator and result type.

Roughly speaking,  you can translate any `Fold` into a foldl-and-map:

```
Fold f z g = map g . foldl' f z
```

And you can go backwards too:

```
foldlMapToFold :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> (b -> c) -> Fold a c
foldlMapToFold = Fold
```

So if you had

```
map g . foldl' f z
```

you can write

```
fold (Fold f z g)
```

If you want to use a `Fold`, think, "how can i describe my operation as a `foldl'` and a `map`?", and then go from there.

The advantage of using the `Fold` type over just normal maps and folds is (apart from performance tweaks) the ability to combine and manipulate multiple `Fold`s as objects using their Applicative instance, and other nice instances too, like Functor, Profunctor, fun stuff like that.  Combining folds encoded as maps-and-foldl's is a bit tedious, but the `Fold` wrapper lets you do it in a cleaner first-class way using the abstractions everyone knows and loves.

For example, if i had

```
fold1 = map g . foldl' f z
```

and

```
fold2 = map g' . foldl' f' z'
```

and I wanted to do

```
fold3 = map (\(x,y) -> foo (g x) (g' y))
      . foldl' (\(x,x') (y,y) -> (f x y, f' x' y')) (z', z')
```

(that is, do both folds on the list in one pas, and recombine the results at the end with `foo`).  It's a big hassle, right?

But i can also just do

```
fold1 = Fold f z g
fold2 = Fold f' z' g'
fold3 = foo <$> fold1 <*> fold2
```

(Note that, even better, using using `Fold` actually keeps `foldl'` strict, because in the example above, the lazy tuples add a layer of indirection and make the fold' lazy again incidentally)